# what's wrong with this line?(Inner class and Outter Class)

Tags: java

```
public class Learning{
    private String temp = "Outter";
    private class Inner{
        private String temp = "Inner";
        public void print(){
            String temp = "Inner function";
            System.out.println(temp);
            System.out.println(this.temp);
            System.out.println(Learning.this.temp);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Inner in = new Inner();//what's wrong with this line?
        in.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: What did your compiler tell you about that line?

Comment: What makes you *think* there's something wrong with it?  Is the compiler giving you an error?  Maybe you'd want to *tell us* that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
Inner in = new Inner();//what's wrong with this line?
```

is using an Inner without an outer class.  There is two ways to fix this

```
Inner in = new Learning().new Inner();
```

or make the class `static`

```
private static class Inner {
```

although as @flkes pints out, the outer instance is used.

Comment: @user3437460 some people think some questions are too bad to answer, I guess.

Comment: It does need the outer instance. it calls `Learning.this.temp`

Comment: Seriously, I think they should down vote the question and not a correct answer if the solution is correct.

Comment: @user3437460 Probably because the answer was incomplete before the edit.

Comment: eclipse:No enclosing instance of type Learning is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Learning (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Learning).